# Yii config.php file issue? JQuery doesn't seem to load

Tags: yii

Using Yii 1.1.14

I have the following code:

```
'clientScript'=>array(
                'packages'=>array(
                    'jquery'=>array(
                        'baseUrl'=>'//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/',
                        'js'=>array('jquery.min.js')
                    ),
                    'jquery.ui'=>array(
                        'baseUrl'=>'//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/',
                        'js'=>array('jquery-ui.min.js'),
                    ),
                ) 
        ),
```

While everything seems to be ok with jqueryui loading, the same doesn't seem to work for jquery. I've looked into the page source, and I see no jquery loaded.

Can anyone spot the reason for this behavior?

Comment: why are you loading jquery and jquery ui externally ? i think its not a good practice. it will always send a call to following two website paths every time when a page loads. try to save them inside your folder and access it.

Comment: can you post a view's code in which you said jquery ui is working?

Comment: mazraara there's some nice considerations to use a CDN instead. But that's not the issue. I'm stating that jquery ui is working, because I look into the page source code, and I see jqueryui script tag there. But I don't see the same of jquery.

Comment: in your view file try defining this, <?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerPackage('jquery'); ?>